# How can find element can be faster with Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I got some issues. After I load a page, I use the following code to reach an element, but it takes more than 20 seconds.

I want to know if a element exists in the page:

```
return WebDriverUtil.driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size() != 0;
```

Comment: It takes this long because you probably used `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait()`

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet I don't know what is under xpath but you can use `findElement` instead of `findElements`.

`findElement` method returns the first occurrence on the page so this could improve your execution time if there is more than just one element with the same xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS selector instead of XPath, CSS selectors perform far better